# pd.MultiIndex from product

Tags: pandas

from pandas documentation:

```
numbers = [0, 1, 2]

colors = ['green', 'purple']

pd.MultiIndex.from_product([numbers, colors],names=['number', 'color'])

MultiIndex([(0,  'green'),

            (0, 'purple'),
            (1,  'green'),
            (1, 'purple'),
            (2,  'green'),
            (2, 'purple')],
           names=['number', 'color'])
```

what I got:

```
MultiIndex(levels=[[0, 1, 2], ['green', 'purple']],
           codes=[[0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2], [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]],
           names=['numbers', 'colors'])
```

can someone please help understand why I got this output by putting in the same code?

Answer (score 1):

That was how previous Pandas versions represent the multiIndex. On my system, Pandas 1.0.3 gives the former and 0.24.2 gives the latter. Make sure your system's version is the same with that of the doc.

See the section "Better repr for MultiIndex" enhancement which was released in [v0.25.0](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew/v0.25.0.html).